# CefSharp browser weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, c#, web-scraping, async-await, cefsharp

I've got a problem with my web-scraper. It should execute a javascript to make some changes on a webpage, then download the source and extract some specific data.

```
bool working = true;

for(int i  = 0; i < urls.Count(); ++i)
{
    working = true;
    ChromiumWebBrowser scraper = new ChromiumWebBrowser(urls[i]);
    scraper.FrameLoadEnd += scrape;

    while(working)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
    }
}

async void scrape(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs args)
{
    ChromiumWebBrowser chrome = (ChromiumWebBrowser)sender;
    if (args.Frame.IsMain && chrome.CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame)
    {
        string script = Properties.Resources.script;
        chrome.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
        string data = "   ";
        do
        {
            string html = await chrome.GetSourceAsync();
            string dataField = "data";
            int dataFieldIndex = html.IndexOf(phoneField);
            data = html.Substring(dataFieldIndex + dataField.Count(), html.IndexOf("<", dataFieldIndex + dataField.Count()) - dataFieldIndex - dataField.Count());
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
        } while (data.Count() == 3);
        addDataToHashSet(data);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Error");
    }
}

private void addDataToHashSet(string data)
{
    data = data.Replace("-", "");
    data = data.Replace(" ", "");
    dataHashSet.Add(data);
    working = false;
}
```

Unfortunately, it's unpredictable. It hangs after few iterations - a proper event with CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame and IsMain is never triggered for some iterations. Could you explain it to me?

[edit]: My Cef initialization below:

```
CefSettings cefSettings = new CefSettings();
cefSettings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("allow-running-insecure-content", "1");
cefSettings.IgnoreCertificateErrors = true;
CefSharpSettings.Proxy = new ProxyOptions(ip: "...", port: "...");
Cef.Initialize(cefSettings);
```

Comment: CanExecuteJavascriptInMainFrame is unreliable currently as CEF isn't reliably sending the message from the render process,  there is already an issue in GitHub for this. Based on the code you've provided you don't need the check in frameloadend, so just remove it.  Your script execution looks like a hack job.

Comment: It actually helped. Please write it as an answer so I could accept it.